# CefSharp how i click button

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

=   Add to Cart

browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.getElementsByClassName('btn_addtocart').click()")

not working pls help ,, thanks

Comment: getElementsByClassName return a collection. Try with document.getElementsByClassName("btn_addtocart")[0].click().

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection which is an array like object. You cannot call click directly on the collection, you must select an element from with the collection.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn_addtocart')[0].click();
```

Personally I prefer to use query selector for fetching a single html element.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn_addtocart').click();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Anything you are having problems with JavaScript I'd suggest running your script directly in DevTools. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

For accessing/automating a certain website at work I had to switch from .NET WebBrowser to CefSharp.
Part of my task is to click a button on that page. Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync ... stuff doesn't work for me:
I can access/read the attributes of an element, but I cannot invoke any method/function.
I guess there is some security magic that keeps me from 'injecting' a click.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Dom does the trick for me.

Comment: I think you should delete the writing about what doesn't work and just include the final sentence about what did work for you along with an explanation of what it is, not just a bare link.